# Service Fabric multiple instances issue

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-stateless

I noticed that when I publish my Service Fabric (in 5 node cluster mode) application (with 2 stateless services) it immediately runs on 5 nodes.

My ApplicationManifest.xml has this:

```
<Parameters>
         <Parameter Name="MyStateless1_InstanceCount" DefaultValue="-1" />
         <Parameter Name="MyStateless_InstanceCount" DefaultValue="-1" />
</Parameters>
```

And my Local.5Node.xml has this:

```
<Parameters>
         <Parameter Name="MyStateless1_InstanceCount" Value="1" />
         <Parameter Name="MyStateless_InstanceCount" Value="1" />
</Parameters>
```

I tried to change values in both xmls in multiple ways but it always starts on 5 nodes. I notice this because I have in one service ServiceInstanceListener on one port and every time I get warning because it`s trying to start on 5 nodes.
How can i fix this?

Also I am new in using Service Fabric so I have few more questions:

1. Is it possible to publish few applications at the same time, like some way/command to publish them simultaneously or is the only way manually one by one?
2. When I have stateful service I understood that it needs to be run on 5 node cluster mode and that runs on minimum three nodes. Is this correct?

EDIT:

[image]

EDIT 2:
Cluster Manifest

```
<ClusterManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="DevCluster" Version="0" Description="This is a generated file. Do not modify." xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <NodeTypes>
    <NodeType Name="NodeType0">
      <Endpoints>
        <ClientConnectionEndpoint Port="19000" />
        <LeaseDriverEndpoint Port="19001" />
        <ClusterConnectionEndpoint Port="19002" />
        <HttpGatewayEndpoint Port="19080" Protocol="http" />
        <HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint Port="19081" Protocol="http" />
        <ServiceConnectionEndpoint Port="19006" />
        <ApplicationEndpoints StartPort="30001" EndPort="31000" />
      </Endpoints>
      <PlacementProperties>
        <Property Name="NodeTypeName" Value="NodeType0" />
      </PlacementProperties>
    </NodeType>
    <NodeType Name="NodeType1">
      <Endpoints>
        <ClientConnectionEndpoint Port="19010" />
        <LeaseDriverEndpoint Port="19011" />
        <ClusterConnectionEndpoint Port="19012" />
        <HttpGatewayEndpoint Port="19082" Protocol="http" />
        <HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint Port="19083" Protocol="http" />
        <ServiceConnectionEndpoint Port="19016" />
        <ApplicationEndpoints StartPort="31001" EndPort="32000" />
      </Endpoints>
      <PlacementProperties>
        <Property Name="NodeTypeName" Value="NodeType1" />
      </PlacementProperties>
    </NodeType>
    <NodeType Name="NodeType2">
      <Endpoints>
        <ClientConnectionEndpoint Port="19020" />
        <LeaseDriverEndpoint Port="19021" />
        <ClusterConnectionEndpoint Port="19022" />
        <HttpGatewayEndpoint Port="19084" Protocol="http" />
        <HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint Port="19085" Protocol="http" />
        <ServiceConnectionEndpoint Port="19026" />
        <ApplicationEndpoints StartPort="32001" EndPort="33000" />
      </Endpoints>
      <PlacementProperties>
        <Property Name="NodeTypeName" Value="NodeType2" />
      </PlacementProperties>
    </NodeType>
    <NodeType Name="NodeType3">
      <Endpoints>
        <ClientConnectionEndpoint Port="19030" />
        <LeaseDriverEndpoint Port="19031" />
        <ClusterConnectionEndpoint Port="19032" />
        <HttpGatewayEndpoint Port="19086" Protocol="http" />
        <HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint Port="19087" Protocol="http" />
        <ServiceConnectionEndpoint Port="19036" />
        <ApplicationEndpoints StartPort="33001" EndPort="34000" />
      </Endpoints>
      <PlacementProperties>
        <Property Name="NodeTypeName" Value="NodeType3" />
      </PlacementProperties>
    </NodeType>
    <NodeType Name="NodeType4">
      <Endpoints>
        <ClientConnectionEndpoint Port="19040" />
        <LeaseDriverEndpoint Port="19041" />
        <ClusterConnectionEndpoint Port="19042" />
        <HttpGatewayEndpoint Port="19088" Protocol="http" />
        <HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint Port="19089" Protocol="http" />
        <ServiceConnectionEndpoint Port="19046" />
        <ApplicationEndpoints StartPort="34001" EndPort="35000" />
      </Endpoints>
      <PlacementProperties>
        <Property Name="NodeTypeName" Value="NodeType4" />
      </PlacementProperties>
    </NodeType>
  </NodeTypes>
  <Infrastructure>
    <WindowsServer IsScaleMin="true">
      <NodeList>
        <Node NodeName="_Node_0" IPAddressOrFQDN="DESKTOP-S5LLM1H" IsSeedNode="true" NodeTypeRef="NodeType0" FaultDomain="fd:/0" UpgradeDomain="0" />
        <Node NodeName="_Node_1" IPAddressOrFQDN="DESKTOP-S5LLM1H" IsSeedNode="true" NodeTypeRef="NodeType1" FaultDomain="fd:/1" UpgradeDomain="1" />
        <Node NodeName="_Node_2" IPAddressOrFQDN="DESKTOP-S5LLM1H" IsSeedNode="true" NodeTypeRef="NodeType2" FaultDomain="fd:/2" UpgradeDomain="2" />
        <Node NodeName="_Node_3" IPAddressOrFQDN="DESKTOP-S5LLM1H" NodeTypeRef="NodeType3" FaultDomain="fd:/3" UpgradeDomain="3" />
        <Node NodeName="_Node_4" IPAddressOrFQDN="DESKTOP-S5LLM1H" NodeTypeRef="NodeType4" FaultDomain="fd:/4" UpgradeDomain="4" />
      </NodeList>
    </WindowsServer>
  </Infrastructure>
  <FabricSettings>
    <Section Name="ApplicationGateway/Http">
      <Parameter Name="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="ClusterManager">
      <Parameter Name="MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
      <Parameter Name="TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
      <Parameter Name="UpgradeStatusPollInterval" Value="5" />
      <Parameter Name="UpgradeHealthCheckInterval" Value="5" />
      <Parameter Name="FabricUpgradeHealthCheckInterval" Value="5" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="Diagnostics">
      <Parameter Name="ProducerInstances" Value="ServiceFabricEtlFile,ServiceFabricPerfCtrFolder" />
      <Parameter Name="MaxDiskQuotaInMB" Value="10240" />
      <Parameter Name="EnableCircularTraceSession" Value="true" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="DnsService">
      <Parameter Name="InstanceCount" Value="1" />
      <Parameter Name="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
      <Parameter Name="AllowMultipleListeners" Value="true" />
      <Parameter Name="EnablePartitionedQuery" Value="true" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="EventStoreService">
      <Parameter Name="MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
      <Parameter Name="TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="FailoverManager">
      <Parameter Name="ExpectedClusterSize" Value="4" />
      <Parameter Name="IsSingletonReplicaMoveAllowedDuringUpgrade" Value="True" />
      <Parameter Name="MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
      <Parameter Name="TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
      <Parameter Name="ReconfigurationTimeLimit" Value="20" />
      <Parameter Name="BuildReplicaTimeLimit" Value="20" />
      <Parameter Name="CreateInstanceTimeLimit" Value="20" />
      <Parameter Name="PlacementTimeLimit" Value="20" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="FaultAnalysisService">
      <Parameter Name="MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
      <Parameter Name="TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="Federation">
      <Parameter Name="NodeIdGeneratorVersion" Value="V4" />
      <Parameter Name="ProcessAssertExitTimeout" Value="86400" />
      <Parameter Name="UnresponsiveDuration" Value="0" />
      <Parameter Name="DiskProbeUnresponsiveDuration" Value="0" />
      <Parameter Name="MemoryProbeUnresponsiveDuration" Value="0" />
      <Parameter Name="NetworkProbeUnresponsiveDuration" Value="0" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="Hosting">
      <Parameter Name="CacheCleanupScanInterval" Value="300" />
      <Parameter Name="DeactivationGraceInterval" Value="10" />
      <Parameter Name="DeactivationScanInterval" Value="60" />
      <Parameter Name="EnableProcessDebugging" Value="true" />
      <Parameter Name="EndpointProviderEnabled" Value="true" />
      <Parameter Name="RunAsPolicyEnabled" Value="true" />
      <Parameter Name="ServiceTypeRegistrationTimeout" Value="20" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="HttpGateway">
      <Parameter Name="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="ImageStoreService">
      <Parameter Name="MinReplicaSetSize" Value="1" />
      <Parameter Name="TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="1" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="Management">
      <Parameter Name="EnableDeploymentAtDataRoot" Value="true" />
      <Parameter Name="ImageCachingEnabled" Value="false" />
      <Parameter Name="ImageStoreConnectionString" Value="file:C:\SfDevCluster\Data\ImageStoreShare" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="NamingService">
      <Parameter Name="MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
      <Parameter Name="TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="PlacementAndLoadBalancing">
      <Parameter Name="MinLoadBalancingInterval" Value="300" />
      <Parameter Name="QuorumBasedReplicaDistributionPerFaultDomains" Value="true" />
      <Parameter Name="TraceCRMReasons" Value="false" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="ReconfigurationAgent">
      <Parameter Name="IsDeactivationInfoEnabled" Value="true" />
      <Parameter Name="LocalHealthReportingTimerInterval" Value="5" />
      <Parameter Name="RAUpgradeProgressCheckInterval" Value="3" />
      <Parameter Name="ServiceApiHealthDuration" Value="20" />
      <Parameter Name="ServiceReconfigurationApiHealthDuration" Value="20" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="Security">
      <Parameter Name="ClusterCredentialType" Value="None" />
      <Parameter Name="ServerAuthCredentialType" Value="None" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="ServiceFabricEtlFile">
      <Parameter Name="DataDeletionAgeInDays" Value="3" />
      <Parameter Name="EtlReadIntervalInMinutes" Value="5" />
      <Parameter Name="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
      <Parameter Name="ProducerType" Value="EtlFileProducer" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="ServiceFabricPerfCtrFolder">
      <Parameter Name="DataDeletionAgeInDays" Value="3" />
      <Parameter Name="FolderType" Value="ServiceFabricPerformanceCounters" />
      <Parameter Name="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
      <Parameter Name="ProducerType" Value="FolderProducer" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="Setup">
      <Parameter Name="FabricDataRoot" Value="C:\SfDevCluster\Data" />
      <Parameter Name="FabricLogRoot" Value="C:\SFDevCluster\Log" />
      <Parameter Name="SkipFirewallConfiguration" Value="true" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="Trace/Etw">
      <Parameter Name="Level" Value="4" />
    </Section>
    <Section Name="TransactionalReplicator">
      <Parameter Name="CheckpointThresholdInMB" Value="64" />
    </Section>
  </FabricSettings>
</ClusterManifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was publishing application in application parameters file section by default was selected `ApplicationParametas\Cloud.xaml` instead of `ApplicationParametas\Local.5Node.xaml`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Would you mind sharing the snapshot of your fabric explorer. I tried your scenario with my sample in 5 nodes and it's working as expected by running 1 instance of each service as you can see below. Also, here is my code sample: https://github.com/krish-gh/SFSample

[image]

Comment: I added snapshot

Comment: Interesting thing happened i tried your application and same thing happened. Your application also created 10 replicas, 5 for each service. So is there something that i need to set in Service Fabric Manager?

Comment: Can you try resetting the local cluster (you will see that option in the same taskbar icon)..just suspecting if it got corrupted somehow..

Comment: I did try that. Even running program (yours and mine) on two computers but same thing happened on both. But i was the one how set local cluster on both so...

Comment: Can you attach the cluster manifest (Manifest tab in the right pane of explorer when you select Cluster root at left pane)

Comment: I still could not reproduce the problem at my end in multiple machines...by any chance any way for a common troubleshooting session?

Comment: I finaly realized what was making problem. When i was publishing application in Application Parametars File section by deffault was selected ApplicationParametas\Cloud.xaml insted of ApplicationParametas\Local.5Node.xaml